# How to delete files if they don't have certain phrases in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10

I have a folder full of log files for Minecraft I copied out to another folder, and I need to delete each file in the current directory without the phrase "* [Iron] BuzzTheGamer23 is no longer AFK" somewhere behind the phrase "BuzzTheGamer23 fell out of the world". If it is not possible to check for both phrases, then just do the first phrase.

I made a script to run and log the find command, but it didn't work well. It gave me a big log file I had to use to find each file. And I struggled to get the file I need, because of the number of files making it easy for me to make a mistake.

My script:

```
find /i "BuzzTheGamer23 fell out of the world" "*.log" >> found.txt
echo Completed
:end
goto end
```

I expected to get a list of files with the phrase in it, but I got a huge file. And, also after using the script, I decided I also needed to detect "* [Iron] BuzzTheGamer23 is no longer AFK" somewhere before it. Here is a slice of the file:

```
---------- 2019-04-13-4.LOG
[13:04:50] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] BuzzTheGamer23 fell out of the world
[13:07:12] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] BuzzTheGamer23 fell out of the world

---------- 2019-04-13-5.LOG

---------- 2019-04-14-1.LOG

---------- 2019-04-14-2.LOG

---------- 2019-04-18-1.LOG

---------- 2019-04-18-2.LOG

---------- 2019-04-26-1.LOG

---------- 2019-04-27-1.LOG

---------- 2019-04-27-2.LOG

---------- 2019-04-27-3.LOG
[13:50:38] [main/INFO]: [CHAT] BuzzTheGamer23 fell out of the world

---------- 2019-04-27-4.LOG

---------- 2019-04-27-5.LOG

---------- 2019-04-27-6.LOG

---------- 2019-04-27-7.LOG

---------- 2019-04-28-1.LOG

---------- 2019-04-28-2.LOG
```

Comment: Well, `find` command does _not_ show the names of the files where the search string appears as you want. It show _the lines_ where the search string appears. If the given file name is a wild-card, then it additionaly shows the name of _each file_ where the search is done... You may enter `find /?` to show a description of what `find` command does. I suggest you to try: `findstr /I /M /V /C:"BuzzTheGamer23 fell out of the world" *.log >> found.txt`. Remember that you may enter `findstr /?` to read a description about `findstr` switches...

Comment: Your requirements sound as if best solved with a regular expression (a more complex one than `findstr.exe` can handle). So either use [jrepl.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) or switch to a script language with full featured RegEx support like PowerShell.